How to calculator modbus RTU timer period?
I'm using the dsPIC33ck128mc105 and the FreeModbus library.
I need to add Modbus RTU (RS232), but I'm facing a small problem. I understand the timer period calculation as "11 bits / UART baud rate * 3.5".
I'm using a 9600 baud rate, but the 4.01ms or 4.04ms settings aren't working. The RX pin is functioning correctly, but the TX pin isn't sending data. I can tell because I have LEDs connected to the RX and TX pins.
I decided to increase the timer period because I was only able to get two values from the U1RXREG. When I changed the timer period to 8.08ms, it worked.
Interestingly, when I tried RTU with 485, it worked sometimes and sometimes it didn't with the 8.08ms setting. I haven't tried RS232 for long, but it has been running fine all day so far.
Why did increasing the timer period to 8.08ms make it work?

Is this a 3, 5 or 7 wire connection?  If it is 5 or 7, you need to take care of the DSR/DTR and RTS/CTS too.  Without that, nothing will happen.  With RS422/485, what connections did you have?

cup / I don't understand your response: "3, 5, or 7." Sorry. //
Here are my connections:
dsPIC RX --> MAX3485 RO //
dsPIC TX --> MAX3485 DI //
dsPIC RTS (using a GPIO pin) --> MAX3485 RE and DE //
Since the dsPIC does not have a dedicated 'UART RTS pin', I am using a GPIO pin for RTS and controlling it with software. I use RTS_SetHigh(); and RTS_SetLow(); functions for this purpose.

You can have a 3 wire connection - tx, rx and gnd.  5 wire - tx, rx, cts, rts, gnd.  7 wire tx, rx, rts, cts, dtr, dsr, gnd.  If you are writing code, edit the original post.  So it looks like you have a 5 wire link.
